# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource for azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting this error when I try to access azure web app(rest api) from a react app.

I modified web apps core to accept CORE origins from "*", but getting same error. But if I disable "Authentication / Authorization" option of azure web app then there is no errors like this. This only happens if I enabled "Authentication / Authorization" with an Azure AD app.

**Access to fetch at 'https://login.windows.net/XXXXXX/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=XXXXX' (redirected from 'https://AAAwebapp.azurewebsites.net/XXXXX') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. I modified my react app with below code .

```
const myHeaders = {}
const myInit = {
method: "GET",
headers: myHeaders,
credentials: "include"
}
```

and fetch part was modified with :

```
fetch('myapi url', myInit)
```

After that enabled Access-Control-Allow-Credentials of the Azure web app.

[image]

Comment: You can feel free to mark this as answer so that others can easily find this solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that CORS is enabled by your Web API resource. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#add-cors-functionality for steps on how to enable that. Note that said steps will only allow CORS from the localhost:5000. In a production environment, you'll want to set allowedOrigins URLs to those you want to grant access to or use '*' to enable all.

Comment: @KalumUmesh Show us.  You probably didn't set it correctly.